# cygwin sed substitution against commands in history

Tags: sed, cygwin, history, substitution

I couldn't find an answer for this exact problem, so I'll ask it.

I'm working in Cygwin and want to reference previous commands using `!n` notation, e.g., if command 5 was `which ls`, then `!5` runs the same command.

The problem is when trying to do substitution, so running:

```
!5:s/which \([a-z]\)/\1/
```

should just run ls, or whatever the argument was for which for command number 5.

I've tried several ways of doing this kind of substitution and get the same error:

```
bash: :s/which \([a-z]*\)/\1/: substitution failed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me using Bash in Cygwin (note that my `which ls` command was number 501 in my history list; not `5` like yours):

`$(!501 | sed 's/which \([a-z]\)/\1/')`

You could also do it this way (which is shorter/cleaner):

`$(!501 | sed 's/which //')`

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can tell the `s/old/new/` history substitution syntax only does simple string substitution; it does not support full regexes. Here's what `man bash` has to say:

> #### `s/old/new/`
>
> Substitute *new* for the first occurrence of *old* in the event line.  Any delimiter can be  used  in place  of `/`.  The final delimiter is optional if it is the last character of the event line.  The delimiter may be quoted in *old* and *new* with a single backslash.  If  `&`  appears  in  *new*,  it  is replaced by *old*.  A single backslash will quote the `&`.  If *old* is null, it is set to the last *old* substituted, or, if  no  previous  history  substitutions  took  place,  the  last  *string*  in  a `!?string[?]` search.

Never fear, though. There are in fact easier ways to accomplish what you are trying to do:

1. `!$` evaluates to the last argument of the previous command:

   ```
   # ls /etc/passwd
   /etc/passwd
   # vim !$
   vim /etc/passwd
   ```
2. `!5:$` evaluates to the last argument of command #5:

   ```
   # history
   ...
   5: which ls
   ...
   # !5:$
   ls
   ```
3. You can also use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> to perform an immediate substitution equivalent to `!$`. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> is one of the best bash tricks I know.